# Safari http site keep loading forever

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network, safari

I found that http sites (e.g., http://eu.httpbin.org/) keep loading forever, which I did not visit before. Safari does not switch it to the HTTPS. Rather, it keeps loading forever; do you have any idea what is happening?

I am using Version 16.6.1, macOS Big Sur.
Thanks

Comment: complete the web address http://eu.httpbin.org/image/jpeg

Comment: Got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on Safari Version 17.3.1 (17617.2.4.11.12, 17617)

http://eu.httpbin.org/image/jpeg

it shows this picture

[image: coyote]

My settings
[image: settings]

Comment: For me, it did not leave this page.

Comment: This could be long explanation , it is in your Safari settings, Try another browser

Comment: I could not view the setting of the link cause safari did not open it.

Comment: did you try anther browser

Comment: Yes, it works fine with many other browsers.